# The compound object is not applicable

Tags: scheme, mit-scheme

I'm writing a small plotting utility for MIT-Scheme. **Source:** [[plotlib]](https://github.com/086709/plotlib/blob/master/plot.scm).

At the top level is the `(make-plot output mode args)` function that takes in an output device object, the plotting mode, and a list containing the parameters for the kind of plot specified in the mode.
I will use the function `(range start stop increment)` to generate lists from inclusive start to exclusive stop for each increment. `(range -1 1 .1)` creates the list `(-1 -.9 -.8 ... .9)`.

`make-plot` works for its other modes, but does not work when called with `'vector-field-plot`

```
(define window (make-graphics-device 'win32))

(define (vector-field-plot device color xrange yrange func) 
  (let* ((cords (append-all (map (lambda (i) 
                                   (map (lambda (j) 
                                          (cond ((eq? j '()) '()) 
                                                (else (cons i j)))) 
                                        xrange)) 
                                  yrange))) 
         (input (map (lambda (point) 
                       (list (car point) (cdr point) 
                             (car (func (car point) (cdr point))) 
                             (cdr (func (car point) (cdr point))))) 
                     cords))) 
    (draw-vector-list device color input)))

;This is the part of make-plot that is called for 
;(make-plot window 'vector-field-plot '(args))

((eq? mode 'vector-field-plot)
       ;does not work yet
        (let* ((bg-color (car args))
               (grid-color (cadr args))
               (line-color (caddr args))
               (xrange (car (cadddr args)))
               (yrange (cadr (cadddr args)))
               (func   (cddr (cadddr args))))
         (clear output bg-color);sets background to white
         (coord-grid-cart output grid-color);prints Cartesian coordinate grid
         (vector-field-plot output line-color xrange yrange func)))))
         ;calls vector-field-plot with parameters given to make-plot
;I have left out some function definitions here, they are in the source file
;but you can assume all of those work correctly for this section
```

One mode of `make-plot` prints vector fields, It calls the function `(vector-field-plot output line-color xrange yrange func)` With xrange and yrange being lists of numbers like `'(-1 -.9 ... 1)` and a func of the form `(lambda (x y) (cons x y))`. If I use:

```
(make-plot window 'vector-field-plot (list "white" "black" "red"
                                           (list (range -1 1 .1) (range -1 1 .1) 
                                           (lambda (x y) (cons (* -.1 y) (* -.1 x))))))
```

It returns `The object (#[compound procedure  ]) is not applicable.`

But if I use:

```
(vector-field-plot window "red" (range -1 1 .1) (range -1 1 .1) 
                                (lambda (x y) (cons (* -.1 y) (*  .1 x))))
```

It displays the correct plot (a circular vector field) in the graphics window.
[image: output]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is because the expression to get the function outside the list of arguments returns a list containing the function, not the function itself.

You should change:

```
(func   (cddr (cadddr args))))
```

with:

```
(func   (caddr (cadddr args))))
```

Comment: @jordan Consider using `third` (or `fourth`) instead of `cadddr`.

Comment: im going to rewrite this to use `list-ref` soon. I actually have some Ideas to shrink it by about 50% SLOC.

Comment: It will make the input simpler because you will be able to call make plot with a flat arg list, instead of a list that contains another list. Or i will use optional arguments. This is a quick implementation to see the capabilities of the graphics operations in the mit/gnu-scheme implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Jordan,

I am trying to resolve the LNK1168 error on Windows 10 that is identical to the one you described in a question a few months ago. I have no other way of contacting you, and since you've obviously coded since then, I assume you've fixed the issue.

What did you do to fix it?

Thanks

Comment: Whats happening is that you are running the program in debugging mode and then not correctly exiting out of the program. The debugger attaches itself to the process your program is running in and the debugger becomes unstable if you prematurely exit from the program (hitting the x on the window). What you need to do to prematurely terminate the program is to hit the red button in the debugger toolbar so that the debugger can close it correctly. Otherwise you need to wait for the program to terminate normally.

Comment: Otherwise run the program without debugging.